# How to repair broken coil?

Tags: oscillator, coil, copper

I am working on my Grandpa's rare old watch which was damaged, the damage is with the coil in which one copper strand is cut. Its an enamel coated copper. How to repair the cut wire? and I want to check whether the quartz crystal is working or not. please help

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words. You can see your problem, we can’t. The watch can't be too old if it is has a quartz crystal.

Comment: "this cut isn't bringing a continuity in the coil" - You'll need to explain that a bit better.

Comment: @Kartman its a 40 years old watch, its circuit is bit tricky

Comment: @Finbarr Yeah I have no idea what this means. Why would you expect a cut in the wire to short the coil? A cut in the wire of a coil opens it (increases resistance to infinite). A nick in the enamel between coils shorts it (decreases resistance).

Comment: @Finbarr It has been edited, please mention if any other information is needed

Comment: Is your coil disconnected in the middle and you needed it connected? Or is it too low resistance and you need it higher? Often the only way to repair coils is to rewind them, no matter what the damage is.

Comment: I think that " isn't bringing a continuity in the coil" is a poor translation that should be "has made the coil discontinuous" or something like that. That could possibly be repaired by scraping the insulation off the two loose ends and soldering a short piece of wire to connect them. That will be a very challenging task, particularly with very thin wire and a very small coil. Another possibility is to make that a new connection point for one end of the coil. That will still be difficult and will alter the coil characteristics.

Comment: By "bring continuity," I believe that you may mean "restore continuity."

Comment: @CharlesCowie Yeah. I think it's a language barrier thing. Because in English "bring" implies a desired result to an action so you can't just negate the result to say that something undesirable has happened. Instead what happens is it makes it sounds like you want the undesirable result.

Comment: Can you hold up a rule to the photo so we can tell how big it is? And is the cut on the outside? If it is, you could take a gamble and slip some thin heat resistant material underneath the two wire ends if they are on the outside and try to solder a tiny piece of wire to connect the two. But if it's magnet wire you have to be real careful. If it's solderable enamel then you need to burn through it without burning anythign else and if it's not you need to scrape or acid etch it away without damaging the rest of the coil, both of which are tough.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes the cut is on outside ! its possible to take the wire and remove the insulation, but the challenge is how to connect it in order to restore the current path

Comment: I would try direct soldering it first but DO NOT FORCE THE HEAT trying to burn through the enamel. You might get lucky and get solder on the expose ends where it was cut but it will be real fragile. Do not apply solder wire directly. Apply with the iron tip and wipe off so there are no obvious blobs. You don't need much in this case and a stray blob will ruin your day. I don't know how fine the wires are but the safest way might be to glue some sandpaper on some tweezers and gently sand away some insulation at the cut ends. You don't want to pull and break the wires either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you have provided a picture, I can have a go at advice.

The only way I can see to repair that coil is to take the two cut ends and peel them back 180 degrees in each direction, scrape enamel off and solder.

This will reduce the number of turns by one, and depending on the tuning capabilities of the circuit may or may not make the circuit unusable.

Alternatively, tease the two ends away from the cut point until they are free of the coil, scrape the ends clean, then solder a (very short) jumper between the two ends, as close as possible to the coil, then insulate and support the bridge wire using something like a couple of drops of epoxy. This will still alter the tuning, but not as much.

As you can imagine, this will be terribly finicky, precise work, probably best carried out with a microscope.

Comment: Practice insulation removal on some other similar wire first. Soldering as well.

Comment: @DKNguyen - I wouldn't want to try it myself.

Comment: The copper should be of a better quality (enough for the experiments?) , I don't feel Longines uses a poor quality of copper

Comment: Probavly best to tin the jumper separately then wipe the tip dry and not add additional solder when connecting. That way you can safely try again and again until you have just a thin tidy solder layer to use. You may need extra flux when soldering to the coil since the flux inside the solder wire may be expended during the first heating.

Comment: Be aware that both ends will probably melt at the same time since short length and high thermal conductivity.

Comment: Any tips to test The crystal oscillator ??

Comment: These are tiny coils, *very* thin wire. The broken wire is often the winding *start* (buried inside) rather than winding *end* (last turn, outside). Start-of-winding is nearly impossible to "tease" out. And soldering such thin wires is very difficult. If you *do manage* a repair, be very proud.

Comment: Rather than test the crystal, look for the **one-pulse-per-second** output from the chip - it drives the coil. If your coil is open-circuit, you might try substituting a resistor (a few hundred ohms perhaps?) for the coil.